# Send cookies with urllib2 python

Tags: python, cookies

**Note**: Driver is logged into  the website "https://www.example.com"

```
import urllib,cookielib
jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies") 
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar)) 
data_str = ''
all_cookies = driver.get_cookies() 
for cookie_name, cookie_value in all_cookies[0].items():
       data_str = data_str+cookie_name+'='+str(cookie_value)+';'
opener.addheaders.append(  ('Cookie', data_str) )
url = "https://www.example.com/path/"
f = opener.open(url)
print f.read()
```

This gives me the login page instead of the actual  page from url. Can anyone help ?